# Omitting "Which was"

Tags: which-that

In the following sentence, I am not sure whether I can omit "which was". Omitting is suggested to me by a famous grammar software. Wouldn't "developed" then (after omitting) refer to environment? I want develop to refer to "principle". Or is it possible? Which rules apply?

> This paper presents a principle for such environments, **which was** developed during and evaluated through a study conducted somewhere, where they build large stuff

Answer (score 1):

You might consider replacing the words 'which was . . .' with the words 'a principle . . .' so that you would have an appositive phrase:

> This paper presents a principle for such environments, **a principle** developed during and evaluated through a study conducted somewhere, where they build large stuff

Here, the verb 'developed' clearly takes 'a principle' as its subject.

Comment: The comma after 'somewhere' remains incorrect. If the original reads say ' ... a study conducted at Elbonia City, where they build large stuff' it becomes correct.

Comment: Yes, except I'd say: conducted somewhere where they build large stuff.

Comment: To be honest I don't really like this solution, it is also not at all the answer to my question. The sentence was clear before and the grammar software was just wrong in suggesting to omit it. But replacing it with "a principle" seems way to empurpled for the scientific context I am writing for. Certainly, you are correct though that it is then unambiguous. Thanks for the answer.